# Group representation in MAGMA

Tags: group-theory, math-software, magma-cas

I worked with MAGMA online and studied the handbook, but I still do not
 know how to print the Cayley table. It is possible to print the elements,
 but the representation is somewhat unuseful. It would be nice, if the
 elements could be set to $1...n$ and the Cayley table would be calculated 
 for some group. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2):

There's an example in the MAGMA handbook of how to do this using the NumberingMap function (Example Grp_SetOperations (H57E15)): http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/579#6066